# How do I set up the following Differential Equation?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, word-problem

so in the following word problem, it seems that I am supposed to solve a differential equation in order to find the function f. However, with the way it is worded, I'm having a tough time actually figuring out what the differential equation is. Can anyone help explain what the word problem is actually telling me? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: $y=2\operatorname dy/\operatorname dx$, with $y(0)=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem says $f(x)=2f'(x)$,

so $f'(x)=\frac12 f(x).$

Can you solve that differential equation?

Comment: I think I can. I am currently attempting to solve it and I got the constant C = 2 ln(2). Is this correct so far?

Comment: $f(x)=C\exp(\frac12x)$ is the solution of the differential equation; given $f(0)=2, $ we have $C=2$

Comment: I don't understand how you got 1/2 x. Sorry, I'm not sure if I am making an algebra mistake, but I keep on getting c = 2ln(2).

Comment: $2=f(0)=C\exp(\frac120)=C$

Comment: I got f(x) = e^{(x+c)/2}

Comment: The problem that I have is that my f(x) is different than yours, and I'm not sure how you f(x) = C exp(1/2 x).

Comment: $e^{(x+2\ln2)/2}=e^{x/2}e^{\ln2}=2e^{x/2}$; I recognize  $f'(x)=\alpha f(x)\implies f(x)=Ce^{\alpha x}$

Comment: Oh, I see what you did. So would that mean that both ways are correct?

Comment: They are both equivalent and both correct, though I find my expression more elegant, and I think it's worth learning to recognize it

Comment: Yes, that is true, I appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$$2\frac{df}{dx}=f\implies \int \frac{2d f}{f}=\int dx+C \implies \ln f^2=x+C \implies f^2=De^{x} \implies D=4$$ Hence $$f(x)=2e^{x/2}.$$

Comment: How did you get ln f^2? Shouldn't it be 2ln (f)?

Comment: @Tanner bot $2\log f$ and $\ln f^2$ are correct and give the same answer,.